# How to specify default view with HttpGet in ASP Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to call a view from Startup.cs (below). The controller is called AppController and the method is Index.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=App}/{action=Index}");
    });
}
```

When I launch my app (http://localhost:8000/) I get a 404 error. I thought that above I was setting the default to map to the `Index` method in `AppController.cs`. I think the issue is that over my Index controller I have an `HttpGet` because I have a form that I want to submit on that page (which is working)

```
[HttpGet("index")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

The index page displays as expected when I go to http://localhost:8000/index. Am I doing something wrong in `Configure`?

Answer (score 3):

You should just use:

```
[HttpGet("")]
```

or just

```
[HttpGet]
```

Instead of

```
[HttpGet("index")]
```

`HttpGet` attribute expects a template so by adding a `string` to this attribute you are saying that your action is hitted only when the relative url is "/Index" so by using absolute URL "http://localhost:8000/index".

If you want the default route to work as you configured it then you should remove the `string` in the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I added the following to [allow for multiple routes to be mapped to the same action](https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-core-demystified-routing-in-mvc/):

```
[HttpGet("")]
[HttpGet("index")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[HttpGet]` will be fine. You should also check the [Routing documentation in ASP.NET Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1)